# Rxjs: How to subscribe to an event only if another event happened before?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two event streams:

```
let mouseDowns = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, "mousedown");
let mouseUps = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, "mouseup");
```

I would like to subscribe to all mouseUps that were preceeded by a mouseDown.

Normally I would just remember a state like so:

```
let isDown = false;
mouseDowns.subscribe(() => down = true);
mouseUps.filter(() => isDown).subscribe(() => console.log("CAPTURED");
```

This feels rather un-"reactive"... What is an elegant way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I just figured it out on my own....

```
mouseDowns.map(() => mouseUps.first()).concatAll().subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for skipUntil

http://jsbin.com/tawide/edit?js,console,output

```
const mouseDowns = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, "mousedown");
const mouseUps = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, "mouseup");

mouseUps
    .skipUntil(mouseDowns)
    .subscribe(x => console.log("CAPTURED"))
```

(For my own knowledge, when is a mouse up not proceeded by a mouse down?)

## EDIT

The above is an answer to your code.  If you only want a single event after an down-up event, I think you need a somewhat ugly scan.

```
// dn: ---d-------d-d----d-|
// up: u----u--u-------u---|

//   : -----e----------e---|
const mouseUp = document.querySelector('.mouseUp'); 
const mouseDown = document.querySelector('.mouseDown'); 
const mouseUp$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(mouseUp, 'click')
  .map(() => false);
const mouseDown$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(mouseDown, 'click')
.map(() => true);
Rx.Observable.merge(mouseUp$, mouseDown$)
    .scan((acc, cur) => {
        if (!cur && acc.downEvent) return ({ event: true, downEvent: false})
        if (cur) return ({ event: false, downEvent: true})
        return ({ event: false, downEvent: acc.downEvent})
        }, {event: false, downEvent: false})
    .filter(x => x.event === true)
    .subscribe(
        x => console.log('event!'),
     (e) => console.log("error",e),
     () => console.log('complete')
);
```

Comment: Note that the the semantics of `skipUntil()` are that after one mouseDown onNext is emitted all following mouseUp onNext's will be emitted regardless if they are again preceded by a mouseDown event

Comment: Please note that I noted the semantics when I made the original note.  Note it mimics exactly what his example code does.

Comment: @D.Walsh: Thanks for your response! To answer your question "when is a mouse up not proceeded by a mouse down?": That's easy... if the mouse is down while the user hits Ctrl+R ;-) Or more realistic: mousedown -> move over the element (if not the entire body) -> mouseup ... But I'm not really interested in mouse-ups and mouse-downs... it was more of a general question - I am a novice at rxjs and trying to understand what it can and can't do. Will try your solution tomorrow! Thank you

Comment: No problem!  Try the bin, edit it, and see if it works.  It's all rolling in there.  The up/down events can be simulated by buttons that I made.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you want to stop listening to mouse ups until the next mouse down.  I mean, if you goal is to have an observable that tells you if the mouse is down, you'd do something like:

```
const isMouseDown = Rx.Observable
    .merge(
        mouseDowns.map(() => true),
        mouseUps.map(() => false))
    .startWith(false);

isMouseDown.subscribe(state => console.log("is mouse down? " + state));
```

If you want to trigger after a down/up sequence then you'd do:

```
const myClicks = mouseDowns.switchLatest(() => mouseUps);
myClicks.subscribe(() => console.log("down/up triggered"));
```